# upload addon vaadin to repository maven.vaadin

Tags: maven, vaadin, add-on, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

good day, I would like to load my addon vaadin in maven vaadin, I have already loaded it in the vaadin directory, but I do not know how to publish it in the maven vaadin repository. I thought that this process was done automatically when uploading it to the vaadin directory, but it is not like that.
Currently, the plugin in the vaadin directory is seen in this way in the maven section:

[image: missing maven]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a look at your component and seems like the license is missing. Here are the steps to choose the license:

- Go to your component view. I guess it's this one? https://vaadin.com/directory/component/juicyaceeditor
- There should be a button called `Edit component` at the top
- Choose `Versions` tab and click `Edit`
- Scroll down and you should see a list of licenses, make sure you provide a license for each license of your component and don't forget to click Save.

The end result should look something like this:

[image]

P/s: Another way to manage your components is by going to `See my components`, from there you can see and edit any component you have uploaded to Directory.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I followed the steps you told me.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your component, and go to the `Versions` tab, you can edit a version to make sure it's marked as `Available`. You should also add at least one supported framework.